# how to save api recive data in local variable

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I have api post request in react like

```
const sendData=new FormData();
    sendData.append('func','list');
    sendData.append('qry',"select * from student ");
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/freact/index.php',
        data:sendData

})
.then((resp)=>console.log(resp.data));
```

and i am receiving this data

```
0: {id: "1", name: "vivek", fname: "manohar", mobile: "8824859583", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/194_axixa_cleaner-better-code-670x335.jpg"}
1: {id: "2", name: "anki", fname: "Sushil", mobile: "267877", photo: "http://localhost/freact/uploaded/student/382_axixa_Ankita.pdf"}
```

how can i loop through it inside the table

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844783/how-do-i-iterate-through-table-rows-and-cells-in-reactjs

Comment: but how to save data in state i am trying .then((resp)=>this.setState(data:resp.data)) then it's not giving me proper data

Comment: try this : then((resp)=>this.setState({data:resp.data}))

Comment: yes sorry i forget {} here but i have {} in my orignal code. it's still giving me null array because i had initalized data sate in null array

Comment: Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194866/how-to-set-state-of-response-from-axios-in-react